Как запретить google_tag_manager отправлять чувствительную информацию?
 "@nuxtjs/auth": "~4.9.1",
 "nuxt": "2.17.1",
 "@nuxtjs/gtm": "~2.3.2",

Отключил init, включаю в плагине. Аутентификация по схеме oauth2.
gtm после включения отправляет событие где указан url с /callback?code=...&state=...
Писал прокси для dataLayer, переопределял переменные типа pageURL, document.url, referer и пр., очищал query почти сразу.
в dataLayer - чисто,
в строке - чисто,
нигде нету, а событие все равно летит и полным урлом
в итоге нашел readOnly запись внутри window.Navigation
Вот как запретить ему это делать? Я много всякого перепробовал, все равно отправляет
